# How do I get the rectangles which would fill out a space *excluding* some other rectangles?

Tags: algorithm, rectangles

Title says it all. For example:
[image: rectangles]
I want to get all the green rectangles, given the red rectangles.
I know the size of the bounding rectangle.

The red rectangles may overlap.

Comment: @xerx593 im trying to *calculate* A-G. I only  have the red rectangles.

Comment: Don't you also have to know the size of the bounding box?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Well yeah, i know that. Edited.

Comment: I can't draw a picture, but what's stopping rectangle E from extending all the way to the top of the bounding box?

Comment: There are multiple ways of building A-G rectangles, do you have constraints on that ? Do you need to get the minimum number of rectangles for instance, or not necessarily ? And then, any configuration with the right number of rectabgles ?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc you're right. didn't notice that

Comment: @gdelab anything works. I need to gray-out the screen except for certain draggable elements, which are not grayed-out

Comment: i now uderstand better and up-vote ... but you know "the coordinates" of the red triangles and "the space" (max/min coordinates)!?

Comment: @xerx593 yeah, I know the coordinates and sizes of "the space", and of the red rectangles

Comment: ...then the "neighbor approach" with duplicate checking seems rational.

Comment: @xerx593 I'm not sure what you mean by "neighbor approach". I only have coordinates for the red rectangles, not the green.

Comment: @FireCubez you are saboteur. Usually everyone would ask you to show your effort on solution , i.e. show some of your code. But everyone got excited and infected with this puzzle... :-)

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny: We just came up with algorithms.  The OP still has to do the work.

Comment: #neighbor_approach: each (red) rectangle has [0-4] (left, top, right, bottom) "neighbor rectangles" ... identify them for each (red) rectangle...and check for duplicates..

Comment: @xerx593 my question is asking how to "identify" them

Comment: Do you require that the number of produced rectangles is minimised?

Comment: @trincot No. Any arrangement of rectangles works, as long as it's correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a divide-and-conquer algorithm; the idea is broadly similar to [quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). I've assumed that the rectangles don't overlap, and that they are all contained within the bounding box, although the boundaries might touch.

- If the bounding box is degenerate (i.e. zero width or zero height), do nothing.
- Otherwise if there are no rectangles, then just yield the bounding box itself.
- Otherwise:

  - Choose a rectangle from the list to be the "pivot".
  - Create new bounding boxes for "above", "left", "right" and "below" the pivot.
  - Build lists of rectangles "above", "left", "right" and "below" the pivot by filtering the list for rectangles which intersect each new bounding box, and clipping them to the bounding box.
  - Recursively subdivide the "above", "left", "right" and "below" bounding boxes by the new lists of rectangles that are within them, respectively.

Each rectangle can be involved in at most 2 of the 4 recursive calls. If the pivot is chosen randomly, and most rectangles don't overlap vertically with most other rectangles, then on average each rectangle is involved in one recursive call. Since the non-recursive work takes linear time, the expected running time in that case is O(n log n) where n is the number of rectangles.

An implementation in Python:

```py
import random
from collections import namedtuple

Rectangle = namedtuple('Rectangle', 'x1 y1 x2 y2')

def intersects(b, r):
    return b.x1 < r.x2 and b.x2 > r.x1 and b.y1 < r.y2 and b.y2 > r.y1

def clip_rect(b, r):
    return Rectangle(
        max(b.x1, r.x1), max(b.y1, r.y1),
        min(b.x2, r.x2), min(b.y2, r.y2)
    )

def clip_rects(b, rects):
    return [clip_rect(b, r) for r in rects if intersects(b, r)]

def split_rectangles(b, rects):
    if b.x1 >= b.x2 or b.y1 >= b.y2:
        pass
    elif not rects:
        yield b
    else:
        # randomize to avoid O(n^2) runtime in typical cases
        # change this if deterministic behaviour is required
        pivot = random.choice(rects)

        above = Rectangle(b.x1,     b.y1,     b.x2,     pivot.y1)
        left  = Rectangle(b.x1,     pivot.y1, pivot.x1, pivot.y2)
        right = Rectangle(pivot.x2, pivot.y1, b.x2,     pivot.y2)
        below = Rectangle(b.x1,     pivot.y2, b.x2,     b.y2)

        yield from split_rectangles(above, clip_rects(above, rects))
        yield from split_rectangles(left,  clip_rects(left,  rects))
        yield from split_rectangles(right, clip_rects(right, rects))
        yield from split_rectangles(below, clip_rects(below, rects))
```

Example: as you can see, it doesn't use a minimal number of rectangles, since there are two on the right-hand side that could be joined together vertically.

[image: example]

If minimising the number of rectangles is important, you would want to consider different bounding boxes for "above", "left", "right" and "below", and do a second pass over the result to join any rectangles together if they have two sides which are equal as line segments.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that gives you one possibility for the green rectangles, not necessarily the same as in the pictures nor always the one with the smallest number of rectangles :

- get the sorted list of all the `y`s that are at the start or at the end of a red rectangle.
- Add 0 at the start and the total height at the end of the list.
- for each (`y1`, `y2`) interval :

  - check which red rectangles are in the horizontal band between `y1` and `y2`, sort them by `x` coordinate
  - Create the sorted list of left coordinates and right coordinates : `left_list[i]` will contain the left boundary of the i-th rectangle (similarly for `right_list`). Add 0 as first element of `right_list` and total width as last element of `left_list`
  - For all i, create a green rectangle between `right_list[i]` and `left_list[i]` on x and between `y1` and `y2` on y.

Comment: "Create a green rectangle between right_i and left_i+1" what are those?

Answer (score 1):

The most simple solution is as follows.

Create two lists `xlist` and `ylist`, for each red rectangle and each corner of it, insert the `x` coordinate of that point into `xlist` and the `y` coordinate into `ylist`. Do the same with the bounding box.

Sort and remove duplicates from `xlist` and `ylist`.

For each two neighbouring elements `x1`, `x2` in `xlist` and each two neighbouring elements `y1`, `y2` in `ylist` (two nested `for` loops), create a new green rectangle using the coordinates `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2` (unless the new green rectangle overlaps with any of the red rectangles).

This will give you more green rectangles than necessary, but you did not give any restrictions, so here it goes ;)

You could easily merge neighbouring green rectangles in one line if you'd like to limit the number of rectangles.

Comment: alright, so I add a *third* for loop (or, maybe use a set for the red rects) checking if the x1, y1, x2,y2 are equal to a red rect?

Comment: Actually they do overlap. Sorry i'm forgetting to add these stuff in the question.

Comment: @FireCubez exactly. For simplicity you can use a hash map of red rectangles. Just take care to write a correct compare/equals and hashcode method

Answer (score -1):

It appears from the picture that rectangle A fills all of the space above red rectangle 1.

Rectangle B fills all the space to the left of the red rectangle 1.

Rectangle C fills all of the space to the right of the red rectangle 1.

Rectangle D is bound by both red rectangles.

Rectangles E - G fill in the remainder of the space (top, right, bottom).

The algorithm seems to be, take each red rectangle and fill the space around it.  Unless there are other constraints, this seems to be the process.